# Return keys and values of object when matching with argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, matching

Aim is to build a function, which takes an array of Objects as first arguments. As a second argument it takes a key and value pair.

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source)
```

Now the function should return an array with all the matching keys and values from the object. For example:

```
whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" })´
```

should return

`[{ first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }]`

And

```
whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }], { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 })
```

should return

```
 [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }]
```

I tried looping through the collection- and through the source array searching for matches. Like this:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  // What's in a name?
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(collection).length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(source).length; j++) {
      if (collection[i].last === source.last) {
        arr.push(collection[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

And in case of this arguments `whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" })`

It not surprisingly works.

What I don't understand is, why I can't generalize the above solution, so that it also works in other cases.

**Why is it not possible to simply give the condition:**

```
if (collection[i] === source)
```

(Pls notice the missing "`Last"` key behind collection and source.)

When I `console.log(source)`, console logs it. So imho the conditional statement above should work and should go to push the matches into the `arr` Array.

**How can I build a function which returns an array with all the matching keys and values from the object.**

```
 function whatIsInAName(collection, source)
```

And why does `(collection[i] === source`) not work?

Thank you.

Comment: Two objects are only `===` if they are the same reference to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

> Why is it not possible to simply give the condition: `if (collection[i] === source)`

Because `objects` are compared by reference values, they are two different objects, so they references are distinct.

Now, you could fix you logic with something like this:

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source)
{
  // What's in a name?

  var arr = [], sourceKeys = Object.keys(source);
  var toPush, key;

  // Iterate over the collection of input objects.

  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++)
  {
    toPush = true;

    // Check if current analyzed object have all
    // required (key, value) pairs.

    for (var j = 0; j < sourceKeys.length; j++)
    {
      key = sourceKeys[j];

      if (!collection[i][key] || collection[i][key] !== source[key])
      {
        toPush = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    // If current object meet the condition, put it on the
    // result array.

    if (toPush)
      arr.push(collection[i]);
  }

  return arr;
}

let input1 = [
  {first: "Romeo", last: "Montague"},
  {first: "Mercutio", last: null},
  {first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet"}
];

console.log(whatIsInAName(input1, {last: "Capulet"}));

let input2 = [
  {"apple": 1, "bat": 2},
  {"bat": 2},
  {"apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2}
];

console.log(whatIsInAName(input2, {"apple": 1, "bat": 2}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter and every. By object.
So here the idea is

1. Use filter on `input arg` to get desired element in output.
2. In callback of filter by `Object.keys` we take the key out of `matchObj arg` and for each key we match value of element with the value we get in `matchObj arg` and filter accordingly.

```js
console.log(whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" }))

function whatIsInAName(input,matchObj){
  return input.filter(e=> Object.keys(matchObj).every(el=> e[el] === matchObj[el]))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate the key/value pairs and return a filtered result.

Actually there is not built-in method to test an object against another to check ig the object contains a sub object.

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    var pairs = Object.entries(source);
    return collection.filter(object => pairs.every(([key, value]) => object[key] === value));
}

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" }));
console.log(whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }], { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```